# how to get a value from a repository with a value which is compared with two fields of a table

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Hi i am new to spring JPA . I have a table which has two columns namely 'active_from' and 'active_to'.Now I would like to get a column which has a date(ie.current date) which has a value between "active_from" and "active_to".How to acheive this using spring jpa repositories.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link you could find query methods to add queries that are not covered by the common jpa repository or with the support creation.

Check 2.3.4 Using @Query in
[JPA repositories](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.3.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html)

Using Query methods you can do that, try something like this.

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

  @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE active_from > :?0 AND active_to < :?0 )
  List<User> findBetweenDate(String currentDate);
}
```